# Naming objects created in a loop

Tags: python, list, object, python-object

I want to create a loop that creates an object if a certain condition is met and then adding it to a list. However, I am unsure how to uniquely name these objects so they can be used/referenced later on. For example something like this:

```
favNumbers = []

numbers = [6, 21, 5, 22]

class favNumber(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

for i in numbers:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        unique_name_for_object = favNumber(i)
        favNumbers.append(unique_name_for_object)
```

How would I gave the `favNumber` objects a unique name?

I was thinking of somehow naming them number1, number2, number3... but I think dynamically naming them would be a bad idea.

Is there a way of doing it without dynamically naming them? It seems as if that would be impossible but I am unsure as to how else I could accomplish it.

Comment: That's a _set_ not a _list_. Big difference between the two.

Comment: Index in a list identifies an object uniquely, why would you need a unique name also?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  Why don't you try to elaborate on what it is you want to achieve and maybe we'll find a better approach?

Comment: `{}` is a dict literal, so you can't append. But this is probably what you need, e.g. `favNumbers['unique_name_for_object'] = favNumber(i)`

Comment: I'd second @AdamHughes suggestion. It's hard to tell whether you *actually* need dynamically generated names, unless you explain what you're trying to achieve. It *can* be done in a language like Python, but it's rarely necessary. It probably suffices to store the objects in a container of some kind (eg. a list or dict).

Comment: If you simply want to generate a list: `[favNumber(i) for i in numbers if isEven(i)]`.

Comment: See [**_Why you don't want to dynamically create variables_**](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).

Comment: @ivanzie Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to name the instances. Just try this one

```
favNumbers = []   
numbers = [6, 21, 5, 22]


class favNumber(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value


for i in numbers:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        favNumbers.append( favNumber(i) )
```

Now, `favNumbers` is a list of all created instances. If you want to get the `value` ot the each instance, just type

```
for fn in favNumbers:
    print(fn.value)
```

Comment: Might as well use a list comp.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake Yup: `favNumbers = [i for i in numbers if i % 2 == 0]`.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake you could. Or you could not. Either is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to generate a list, you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
favNumbers = [favNumber(i) for i in numbers if n % 2 == 0]
```

The last expression (`if n % n == 0`) acts as a filter. To access the values, you use an index (eg. `favNumbers[0]` for the first item), or loop through the list like you did with `numbers`.

---

As someone pointed out in the comments, `{}` is a `dict` and cannot be appended to. You *can* however insert items given a key (which might as well be the integer `i`, although it usually makes more sense to use lists when the keys are consecutive non-negative integers).

```
for i in numbers:
  if n % 2 == 0:
    favNumbers[i] = favNumber(i)
```

It can also be done with a dictionary comprehension:

```
favNumbers = { i : favNumber(i) for i in numbers if n % n == 0 }
```

---

I'll update the answer if you provide additional context.